# Does the position of brackets and whitespace affect compiler times and/or run-time?

Tags: c++, compilation

Often while looking at other people's code, I notice a variance in bracket placement for blocks.

For instance, some use:

```
int foo(){
    ...
}
```

Whereas others use:

```
int foo()
{
    ...
}
```

And a number of ways in between. Does this at all affect how fast the code is compiled? For instance, if I were to have a series of blocks such as:

```
int foo() { ... {... {... {... {...} } } } }

int bar()
{
    ...
    {
        ...
        {
            ...
            {
                ...
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Where foo() and bar() are identical except for whitespace and bracket placement. Would the functions take different times to compile? Would one be faster at runtime than the other?

Would this be any different if this were to be expanded to several hundred or thousand nested blocks? Does this change based on the compiler used? Would it change for different languages, such as C#, PHP, Perl, etc?

Sorry if this seems like a lot of general or open-ended questions, just something that's always interested me.

Comment: Not in the slightest. (Well, the compiler has to read the whole file, so padding it with lots of whitespace takes minutely longer to read I suppose. But definitely no difference of any kind at runtime. The whitespace is gone entirely by then.)

Comment: "Would this be any different if this were to be expanded to several hundred or thousand nested blocks?" Yes. You would be murdered and all of your coworkers would mysteriously claim to have seen nothing.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Theoretically, of course. Anyone that actually did that would be drawn and quartered.

Comment: If it looks ridiculous, it is ridiculous.  Make a function from the inner parts of the loop.  See if there is a STL algorithm that does what you want. Do anything but use more then *n* nested loops; people argue about the proper value of *n*, so I'll leave that for discussion.  Oh, and hanging always came before drawing and quatering.

Comment: It clearly affect the time it takes me to understand and maintain the code.

Answer (score 1):

> Would the functions take different times to compile? Would one be faster at runtime than the other? Would this be any different if this were to be expanded to several hundred or thousand nested blocks? Does this change based on the compiler used? Would it change for different languages, such as C#, PHP, Perl, etc?

No. No. No. No. No. Virtually all sane compilers strip out whitespace almost immediately in the lexing phase. The other phases don't even know that there *was* whitespace.

The only way in which this could make any difference is the most hideously incompetently written compiler ever, and even then I'd be amazed (also a bug of this magnitude would make it so buggy it would be completely unusable).

Comment: It seems I have a lot to learn about compilers. I look forward to my compiling class in the fall.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing a compiler will do is perform [lexical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) to strip whitespace, comments, etc and transform the input into a series of tokens.

The full process is similar to the following, depending on the specific implementation:

---

[image]

---

Since the lexer passes a series of tokens to the parser any additional whitespace, bracket positions, etc could potentially slow down only the lexing phase. And even then the difference will not be noticeable unless you had an extreme case, like a GB of whitespace or something crazy like that.